# Read argument from bash script and pass it to awk command

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I wants to execute an **awk** command from bash script. I am passing file path as an argument to bash script, but that argument is not working in **awk** command.

My bash file **mybash.sh** code:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"

echo $file

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF!=5{print "not enough fields"; exit} NR == 1 && ($1 != "nasme" || $2 != "designation" || $3 != "email" || $4 != "phone" || $5 != "group") {print "Wrong file headers"; exit}' $file
```

If I run bash file as :

> bash mybash.sh /home/file_path.csv

my script prints **$file** as exactly the path I have given, but my **awk** command is not reading this **$file**, because it prints **NF** as 0 always. However above awk command works fine directly from Terminal.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF!=5{print "not enough fields"; exit} NR == 1 && ($1 != "name" || $2 != "designation" || $3 != "email" || $4 != "phone" || $5 != "grsoup") {print "Wrong file headers"; exit}' /home/file_path.csv
```

Comment: note: it is bad practice to name scripts ending in `.sh`. If you do chmod +x «script-name», then you can run it as `mybash /home/file_path.csv`

Comment: Why do you bother with a filename at all? Let your script read from standard input and use `./mybash.sh </home/file_path.csv` (just remove the `$file` at the end of the `awk` command line in the script).

Comment: @Kusalananda can you see what is wrong. Maybe put $file in double quotes. If not then filenames with spaces will not work.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No, I can't really see what's wrong, but `$file` is being used unquoted. Instead, use `"$file"`.  This would matter if the pathname contained whitespace characters. This would also not matter if the `awk` program was made to read from the standard input of the script, which is why I suggested it.

Comment: We might have to see the first few lines of the file, and also to know what the actual pathname is that is passed to the script.

Comment: Also note that while you say that "it prints `NF` as 0 always", the code does not actually print `NF` at all, so we don't know that you do the same thing when you are seeing these zeros.

Comment: I wonder if  your file has DOS-style CRNL line endings, but you're not reporting "file not found" errors. Do `cat -e mybash.sh` and see if you have `$` characters at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the something like the following:

```
file="$1"

cat $file | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NF!=5{print "not enough fields"; exit} NR == 1 && ($1 != "nasme" || $2 != "designation" || $3 != "email" || $4 != "phone" || $5 != "group") {print "Wrong file headers"; exit}' > someoutputfile
```

Comment: And how would `$file`'s contents be piped to the `awk` script?

Comment: You may as well turn it into a proper `awk` script without involving a shell at all.

Comment: I am still learning to, would like to know how? @Kusalananda

Comment: Without knowing what the cause is of the user's issue (there's nothing fundamentally wrong with their code except for the non-quoting of `$file`), I won't be writing an answer. I'm treating this question as "unclear" since we don't have all the information.